# Update single value in SQL table in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to update a value in a SQL .db file that only has 1 row in 1 table. I just want to change the CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE column though.

```
    public static final String CUSTOMER_TABLE = "CUSTOMER_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_EMAIL = "CUSTOMER_EMAIL";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PASSWORD = "CUSTOMER_PASSWORD";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMRER_ISMEMBER = "CUSTOMRER_ISMEMBER";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE = "CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PAYMENTERROR = "CUSTOMER_PAYMENTERROR";
    public static final String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_AUTOCARDTOKEN = "CUSTOMER_CARDTOKEN";

public void upDateActiveStatus(boolean isActive){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String SS = "UPDATE " + CUSTOMER_TABLE + " SET " + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE  + "=" + isActive + " WHERE " + "ID = 1";
        db.execSQL(SS);
```

But this is not working. Because when I pull the value of isActive later (I know this part works) It is unchanged.
Any ideas?

This was my error : `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: true (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE CUSTOMER_TABLE SET CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to update the table is by using the method `update()` with `ContentValues`.
The method `update()` also returns the number of affected rows which you can check.
So do it like this:

```
public int upDateActiveStatus(boolean isActive){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ISACTIVE, isActive ? 1 : 0);
    int rows = db.update(CUSTOMER_TABLE, cv, "ID = ?", new String[] {"1"});
    db.close();
    return rows;
}
```

You can call the method like this:

```
int rows = upDateActiveStatus(true);
```

and then check the value of the variable `rows` to check the number of the updated rows.